# Клик на элементе TreeItem

Tags: java, javafx

Есть дерево с 5-ю элементами. Как реализовать клик мышкой на item1 и item2?

Например чтобы при нажатии на один из этих элементов скрывалась кнопка btn1;

Вот что пока у меня есть

```
public class SelectsController {
    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> treeView;
    @FXML
    private VBox treeVbox;

    public void initialize() {
        setTreeView();
    }

    private void setTreeView() {
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Выборки");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Выборка №1");
        TreeItem<String> item2 = new TreeItem<>("Выборка №2");
        TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Выборка №3");
        TreeItem<String> item4 = new TreeItem<>("Выборка №4");
        TreeItem<String> item5 = new TreeItem<>("Выборка №5");

        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);

        treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);

        treeVbox.getChildren().add(treeView);

        item1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            System.out.println("00000000000");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вешайте на элемент обычный слушатель на клик и в нем описывайте все необходимые действия. Не совсем понятно, в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Как это сделать непонятно. Нормального примера где это реализовано не нашла. Можете привести простой пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой пример. Добавляйте это в свой метод и каждый раз, когда кликните на элементе item1, в консоли получите Clicked. Обратите внимание, что в этот метод передаются все события, а уже условный оператор определяет, что это именно клик. Как сделать рациональнее, подумайте сами.

```
label.addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType.ROOT, (javafx.event.Event event) -> {
    if (javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED == event.getEventType()) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Я так и делала, просто думала есть вариант как с кнопками типа AddClickListener. Спасибо.)